# NSString's isEqualToString: seems to erroneously report non-equality

Tags: cocoa, nsstring

I'm trying to compare the equality of two multi-line strings.  I'm getting one of the strings from a web service, and the other I'm getting from iTunes via the Scripting Bridge.  The strings from the web service are eventually transferred to iTunes, so if I do that and then re-compare the strings, ideally they'd be identical.

However, when comparing strings like this, it seems that isEqualToString: always returns non-equality.  I'm testing this by testing equality of a string from iTunes that originally came from the web service, and a string directly from the web service.

Logging both strings to the Console produces output from both strings that appears identical.  Logging the lengths of the strings produce identical lengths.

I've also tried comparing the strings using some other methods.  For example, I converted them to ASCII strings to make sure it wasn't some Unicode issue:

```
        NSData *iTunesStringData = [[self iTunesString] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                     allowLossyConversion:YES];
        NSData *webServiceStringData = [[self webServiceString] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                     allowLossyConversion:YES];


        NSString *newiTunesString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:iTunesStringData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
        NSString *newWebServiceString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:webServiceStringData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];

        BOOL result = [newiTunesString isEqualToString:newWebServiceString];
```

Same problem, not equal.  I've tried comparing just the first character:

```
        NSComparisonResult result = [newiTunesString compare:newWebServiceString
                                                            options:NSLiteralSearch
                                                              range:NSMakeRange(0,1)
                                                             locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

Does not return NSOrderedSame.  I've logged these first characters to the Console and they seem identical.  I also considered differences in carriage returns, and tried replacing @"\r" with @"" in both strings before comparing, which doesn't work (and besides, that shouldn't affect equality of just the first character).  I don't want to remove @"\n" characters because I want to preserve the multiple lines.

What's going on?  Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you tried grabbing unichar buffers from each string and iterating over them in parallel to find out where they differ?

Comment: You could also try using one of the methods `-precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping` or `-precomposedStringWithCompatibilityMapping` and seeing if that makes a difference.

Comment: What if you write each string's `dataUsingEncoding:` UTF-8 (or ASCII) to a file and diff them, or hex-dump them and diff the hex-dumps?

Comment: One last suggestion - use `-compare:` on the string. Not `-compare:options:` with `NSLiteralSearch`, just plain `-compare:`.

Comment: None of these suggestions worked.  Although, I figured out that it was indeed the line endings in the strings that were causing the problems.  Weird, though, that comparing the first character using compare:options:range:NSMakeRange(0,1) locale: would fail, even though the first characters are genuinely identical.

In any case, standardizing the line endings and then comparing the strings with isEqualToString: fixed the problem.

Comment: Err.. that was a misstatement.  -precomposed* and -compare: didn't work.  Iterating over the unichar buffers and dumping to a file and diffing them is what confirmed that line endings were the problem.

Comment: Simone: How, exactly, did the line endings differ between the two texts?

Comment: Peter: The line endings for the text coming from iTunes was terminated with Mac line endings (CR), while the text from the web service was terminated with UNIX line endings (LF).  That's what the diff said, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this problem *was* related to line endings.  But since I'm comparing multi-line strings, I didn't want to completely strip out the newlines.  I normalized the line endings like so:

```
        NSString *normalizediTunesString = [[[self iTunesString] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
        NSString *normalizedWebServiceString = [[[self webServiceString] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
```

Then, comparing the strings via compare: worked as expected.

Comment: There's no need to join the splits again. Compare the arrays directly, results will be identical.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing here but maybe use this clean up your strings

```
stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]
```